# If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, show that every eigenvalue of $A$ is nonnegative if and only if $A=B^2$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, show that every eigenvalue of $A$ is nonnegative if and only if $A=B^2$ for some symmetric matrix $B$.

My idea was to make use of the fact that $A$ is symmetric and thus orthogonally diagonalizable (spectral theorem). Therefore, $A$ can be written as $QDQ^T$. However, I am not sure how to continue from there. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: $B^2$ only has nonegative eigenvalues eigenvalues and for the other one look here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349393/proving-that-if-a-is-diagonalizable-with-non-negative-eigenvalues-then-a-b2/349397#349397

Comment: @Dominic Are "eigenvalues eigenvalues" an elite class of eigenvalues? ;-)

Comment: those are eigenvalues squared and hence non negative ;) stupid typo thanks

Comment: Hint: A standard way to prove things about real symmetric matrices, is to first prove it for diagonal matrices.

Comment: Hint: find a square root matrix for $D$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Oh haha I completely forgot about that proof somehow :P. I've been doing too many similar Linear Algebra excercises lately I guess haha. Thanks for reminding me. Could you explain me though why $B^2$ has only positive eigenvalues?

Comment: @cruise suppose $\lambda$ is a eigenvalue of $B$ with eigenvector $v$ then $$B^2 v= B (Bv)=B (\lambda v)=\lambda(Bv)=\lambda^2 v$$

Comment: Thank you again as always :D. I appreciate it a lot :D!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track:

Symmetric B can be rewritten as $S \Lambda S^{-1}$ since symmetric matrices are always diagonalizable. So, $B^2 = S \Lambda S^{-1} S \Lambda S^{-1} = S \Lambda^2 S^{-1}$

Therefore, all the eigenvalues are squares of real numbers(property of symmetric matrices), so the eigenvalues are all positive.

Comment: Thank you! Why are all the eigenvalues squares of real numbers though? Does that follow because of the $\Lambda^2$? How can I see that this is a property of symmetric matrices?

Comment: There's a proof [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/positive-definite-matrices-and-applications/symmetric-matrices-and-positive-definiteness/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses3.1sum.pdf) on the second page.